# How do I say thanks to someone who sends me a message from my site?

Tags: idioms

I'm building my own website.  I have a form that a visitor can request my CV, and I've added a label showing this line of text: "Thanks for your concern, I'll send you my CV soon." Is this sentence proper? I read on other websites that *concern* is much used to express empathy or worry. If this is the case, what is the best wording for my situation?

Comment: Replace with "concern" with "interest" and it will sound better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct as the *OED* defines [**concern**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concern) as

> 1 - *[mass noun]* Anxiety; worry

I would recommend [**interest**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interest):

> 1 - *[mass noun]* The feeling of wanting to know or learn about something or someone.

I feel that perfectly sums up what a person requesting your CV wants.